# How can I deal with sub type in Java?

Tags: java, types, subtype

Hi this is what I've got in the Modula 2 code,

```
TYPE
    TypeA = TypeB;
PROCEDURE Extend(Var: TypeA): TypeA;
BEGIN
    RETURN Varrr: TypeA;
END Extend;
```

So I already have a type B, now I need to make it a new type called type A, so all type A is type B and then how can I do to be able to use make TypeA so I can declare a variable using

```
TypeA var;
```

when I only have TypeB now. In java. Thanks in advance.

I suppose I can do this:

```
class TypeA extends TypeB{
}
```

is this Ok or there is better solution?

Comment: This seems to be an extremely basic question, one that's best answered by opening any intro to Java textbook or tutorial. Surely you've done a little bit of searching and effort to solve this, right? What have these efforts shown you?

Comment: **Why** have you posted an example of Modula 2? ***Who*** has *used* Modula 2 in the last twenty years? How about [Oberon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon_%28programming_language%29)? Would that help?